# Python | How would I put this into multiple threads and allow the GUI to update?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm working on a sub alert system with a GUI, the problem I'm having is the GUI freezes because I'm running a loop that checks chat.

How would I incorporate this existing GUI and Chat code into a system where the GUI won't freeze and the textfield will update with what console has.

```
# Import Resources #
import re
import socket
import importlib
from Tkinter import *
from modules.IRCCommands import *

recentSub= 'N/A'

# Close application #
def Close_Window():
    frmMain.destroy()

# Main application #
def Start():
# List info in the shell #
terminal.insert('1.0', 'Subscriber Alert ver. 1.5 | Created & Modified by RubbixCube' + "\n")
terminal.insert("end", 'Important Information:' + "\n")
terminal.insert("end", 'HOST = ' + HOST + "\n")
terminal.insert("end", 'PORT = ' + str(PORT) + "\n")
for c in CHAN:
    terminal.insert("end", 'CHAN = ' + c + "\n")
terminal.insert("end", '\n' + "\n")
terminal.insert("end", 'Chat:' + "\n")
frmMain.update_idletasks

## Define basic Functions ##
def get_sender(msg):
    result = ""
    for char in msg:
        if (char == "!"):
            break
        if (char != ":"):
            result += char
    return result

def get_message(msg):
    result = ""
    i = 3
    length = len(msg)
    while i < length:
        result += msg[i] + " "
        i += 1
    result = result.lstrip(':')
    return result

## End Helper Functions ##

def parse_message(channel, user, msg):
    if len(msg) >= 1:
        msg = msg.split(' ')
        frmMain.update_idletasks


con = socket.socket()
con.connect((HOST, PORT))

send_pass(con, PASS)
send_nick(con, NICK)
for c in CHAN:
    join_channel(con, c)

data = ""


while True:
    try:
        data = data+con.recv(1024)
        data_split = re.split("\r\n", data)
        data = data_split.pop()

        for line in data_split:
            #print(line)
            #line = str.rstrip(line)
            line = str.split(line)

            # Stay connected to the server #
            if (len(line) >= 1):
                if (line[0] == 'PING'):
                    send_pong(con, line[1])

                if (line[1] == 'PRIVMSG'):
                    sender = get_sender(line[0])
                    message = get_message(line)
                    channel = line[2]
                    terminal.insert("end", sender + ": " + message + "\n")
                    frmMain.update_idletasks

                    # Welcome new subs #
                    if (sender == "rubbixcube"):
                        def excuteCommand(con, channel, user, message, isMod, isSub):
                            msg = str.split(message)
                            if re.match('\w* subscribed for \w* months in a row!', message):
                                recentSub = msg[0]
                                print(recentSub)
                                send_message(con, channel, 'Thanks for your continued contribution %s!' % msg[0])
                            elif re.match('\w* just subscribed!', message):
                                recentSub = msg[0]
                                print(recentSub)
                                send_message(con, channel, str.format('Welcome to the channel %s. Enjoy your stay!' % msg[0]))
                            elif (re.match('\w* viewers resubscribed while you were away!', message)):
                                send_message(con, channel, 'Thanks for subscribing!')
                        excuteCommand(con, channel, sender, message, False, False)

                    parse_message(channel, sender, message)

    except socket.error:
        print("Socket died")

    except socket.timeout:
       print("Socket timeout")



## GUI ##
# Start loop of program
frmMain = Tk()

app = Frame(frmMain)
app.grid()

# Configure GUI
frmMain.title('Subscriber Alert ver. 2.0')
frmMain.geometry('455x357')
frmMain.resizable(0,0)

# Button
start = Button(app, text='     Start     ')
start['command'] = Start
start.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)

close = Button(app, text='      Exit       ')
close['command'] = Close_Window
close.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=5)


# Label
sub_lbl = Label(app, text='Most Recent Subscriber:')
sub_lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, padx=5)

sub_lbl2 = Label(app, text=recentSub)
sub_lbl2.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=10, padx=5)


# Console
terminal = Text(app, width=56, height=17, wrap=WORD)
terminal.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=3)


# End loop of Program
frmMain.mainloop()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"GUI-freezes issues" are common questions with network applications in Python. Usually either your network socket or stream is callign a blocking or timeouts are set to long, pipes and io stream are not finished being flushed or you GUI's reactor is not setup to work with your network io reactor (mainloop).

Typical workarounds are threading network io often with queue.Queue(), or use a network package that supports events, as GUIs are event driven. Twisted and asyncio offer event driven io. Or as often provided now some GUI packages and networking packages have "reactors" (mainloops) that where written to work with other specific packages. Twisted has reactors for TKinter and wx for example.